# Need a powershell script to use a parameter to manipulate/read in fields from another csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have and existing PowerShell script (not written by me!) which is designed to use a passed-in parameter (SCOM Alert ID) to then set additional information in the alert, e.g. $alert.CustomField1 = $alert.PrincipleName etc etc.

I am looking to add functionality to this script to be able to add additional 'custom' information which is stored in a separate text/CSV file.  The text/CSV file has header line

```
ServerName,ServiceOwner,Application Tier
```

so a row in the file would be

```
MYSERVER.CONTOSO.COM,Joe Bloggs, Tier 1
```

There will be one unique row for each server in our environment (over 600 rows).

So what I need to do is using the passed-in alert ID. I can use `$alert.PrincipleName` to find the corresponding row in the text file and pull in the additional details stored in field 2 and 3, i.e. `ServiceOwner` and `ApplicationTier`.

This logic holds for the majority of alerts but IF server name is a specific value (e.g. `MYSTSERVER.CONTOSO.COM`) then instead of using `$alert.PrincipleName` to match servername in text file, I need to match on another alert property `$alert.MonitoringObjectDisplayName`. However, the server name in this field is part of a larger string in the format, e.g. `User Services Watcher for Pool [MYTARGETSERVER.CONTOSO.COM]` - so I need to extract the severname from between the square brackets  of the string to then perform the match with the text file.

Hopefully I have explained what I'm trying to do clearly - if not I'm happy to provide further clarification and can also post up the existing PS Script I'm trying to modify if thats any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can react to the server name like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
...
if ( $alert.PrincipalName -eq 'MYSTSERVER.CONTOSO.COM' ) {
  if ( $alert.MonitoringObjectDisplayName -match '.*\[(.*?)\]' ) {
    $targetserver = $matches[1]
  }
} else {
  $targetserver = $alert.PrincipalName
}

$newdata = $csv | ? { $_.ServerName -eq $targetserver } `
                | select ServiceOwner, 'Application Tier'
...
$alert.CustomField2 = $newdata.ServiceOwner
$alert.CustomField3 = $newdata.'Application Tier'
...
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, just returning to work from a short holiday hence late reply!!  Thanks for the code snippet above - I sort of follow it but am a bit confused on the allocation of values in the file depending on servername.  If I give the powershell I am specifically trying to alter, could you maybe assist with amending it accordingly to provide my required functionality?  Hope you can help - powershell is below and Ive tried adding a few bits which are not working - I've put my comments as ## to seperate from original script annotations.  Any help Much appreciated!!

Comment: Actually cant post up the complete powershell - its not very long but exceeds the allowed chars.  Could I mail you the script or any other way I can post it up on this forum?

Comment: Hi Ansgar - I couldnt trim sufficiently so I've pasted the entire Powershell to Pastebin (not very big!) as you suggested here http://pastebin.com/TmVuBT9x If theres anything you need me to clarify please let me know as I'd love to get this script working.  Any help MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I tried it by embedding your updated snip into original poweshell just after the if statement ie If (!$alert.CustomField3) { - I just pasted in your code (I commented out the Update of Custom2 and 3 from original).  Unfortunately it doesnt seem to work, the powershell does execute as the other custom fields which the script updates does get updated, but Custom 2 and 3 is blank.  I checked the path to csv etc and cant see any errors?

Comment: Any suggestions or any way you can modify the code I posted up in Pastebin? Or would it help if I pasted up the csv file. Anything you need clarified I'm happy to supply.  Thank again!

Comment: Is the code inside the `if (!$alert.CustomField3) {...}` running at all? Do `Write-Host $newdata.ServiceOwner` and `Write-Host $newdata.'Application Tier'` show the correct values?

Comment: Hi, yes code IS runing inside the IF - I've added Write-Host lines throughout (for debugging) and they output to console.  I also added a write-host $csv to check file was being read which it was. BUT I done a write-host $newdata and write-host $targetserver but it does NOT output anything.  I assume thse parameters should have values which should be outputting to console with write-host?

Comment: Think possibly the Parameter $targetserver is empty and so the remaining code the required that param not working?  Is there any other checking I can do?

Comment: I've been meaning to ask this before: is `PrincipleName` perhaps a typo and it should actually be `PrincipalName`? That would explain why `$targetserver` is empty.

Comment: Yes you are quite right - it is a typo and should be PrincipalName - Doh!!  Just running some testing now to check that it works for both PrincipalName and the case where need to used MonitoringObjectDispalyName.  Fingers crossed - I'll report back and MANY thanks for help on this so far!!

Comment: Ansgar, I've tested several scenarios and made a few tweeks to suit my environment, but the good news is all looks to work now.  This solution now opens up many possibilities for managing our SCOM monitoring environment which isn't possible out of the box and has been an area I've be trying to get a solution for some time.  So just to say a massive thankyou for this, you've been a great help and cant thank you enough!! Cheers...